# Oracle subquery funniness

Tags: sql, oracle, in-subquery

Imagine a query

```
SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_A WHERE Col_A IN (SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_B)
```

Except, TABLE_B does not have a Col_A column; Only TABLE_A has it. I tried this in Oracle 12 and I'm not sure how far back in versions it goes but it looks like is returns a valid result of showing all of Col_A data from TABLE_A. As a developer I'm expecting something like this to throw an error since the inner query does not even access the TABLE_A again so to speak. Can someone explain why or where we would use a query situation like the one above because I almost feel like it should be a bug in the system.

Comment: explain exactly  .. version and right context you have a real evidence of this    ..

Comment: @scaisEdge - you can test this easily: In the `SCOTT` schema, try `select sal from emp where sal in (select sal from dept)` - and then change `sal` to `comm` (three times) to see what happens when there are `NULL` in the column. Or if you don't have access to `SCOTT`, try it on any two tables, really - just make sure the column does not exist in the second table. Also, the version and context are irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Which is why the recommended thing to do is to **always** include table references for columns (eg, `Table_b.col_a`).  Stops this type of error dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a bug. As you did not qualify the column, Oracle interprets it as the current column value from table A -- which is within scope (cf. a [correlative sub query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)). So the subquery just produces as many duplicates of that column value as there are rows in table B.

The `in` condition will either become true or false based on that. It will always be false when table B is empty. It will also be false in cases where `Col_A` is null. But in all other cases it will be true. So you'll get as many results as there are rows in table A that have a non-null value in `Col_A`, except when table B is empty, in which case you get no results.

Comment: The subquery being correlative explains why it has access to the matching column name in `TABLE_A`, but that doesn't explain why the subquery's `FROM` clause is ignored. The subquery would fail as a standalone `SELECT` statement.

Comment: @MagnusLindOxlund, what do you mean with *"the subquery's `FROM` clause is ignored"*? It is not: if table B is empty, the result will be different than when it is not.

Comment: Yes, when `TABLE_B` has a `Col_A`, the subquery works as expected. What I mean is when there is no `TABLE_B.Col_A`, the subquery is evaluated as if it reads `(SELECT Col_A)` instead of `(SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_B)`.

Comment: I am referring to the case presented by the asker: `TABLE_B` has no `Col_A`. The subquery still uses the `FROM` clause, since the output is different when `TABLE_B` is empty (i.e. has no rows) or not.

Comment: It's true that if `TABLE_B` is completely empty, the output will be an empty result set. The question describes a scenario where the statement outputs everything from `TABLE_A.Col_A`. That happens when `TABLE_B` has at least one row (the row's contents is irrelevant). The only effect the `FROM TABLE_B` clause seems to have is to confirm that (1) `TABLE_B` exists; and (2) it isn't completely empty. Beyond those checks, the clause is completely ignored.

Comment: In other words, `SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_A WHERE Col_A IN (SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_B);` is identical to `SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_A WHERE Col_A IN (SELECT TABLE_A.Col_A FROM TABLE_B);` which in turn is identical to `SELECT Col_A FROM TABLE_A WHERE Col_A IN (SELECT TABLE_A.Col_A);`. I would expect that second statement to raise an error. The question is why doesn't it?

Comment: So we agree that the clause is not *completely* ignored. As to your `FROM`-less query, that seems to be a different question.